# Notation for nested factors that are random variables in R

Tags: r, variance, random-variable, linear-model

I need to compute the estimate the variance component for my data.

I have the following model, y = gene, cell line, gene*cell line, DNA extract[cell line]

How do I write this for the lme function?  I am confused on how to indicate that "DNA extract" is nested within "cell line" and also have it marked as a random variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
lmer(y ~ gene + cell-line + gene*cell-line + (1|cell-line/DNA-extract))
```

Assuming that `gene` and `cell-line` are numeric, you'll need to make sure that your factors are identified as such in your data frame otherwise R will analyse them incorrectly. If they're character, you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

If the nesting within the function does not work then it may be usefull to create an extra variable where DNA extract is already in the right order:
y = gene, cell line, gene*cell line, Ordered_DNA extract